# How to add custom field in access token (JWT) generated through keycloack?

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, keycloak, access-token

I am working on a spring-boot project where we are using keycloak for authorization. I have to update the access-token coming from keycloak with some additional details.

I have tried many jwt libraries and oauth springboot but not able to achieve it

Comment: *I have to update the access-token* - A JWT is signed, you can't just add anything to an existing token. This would invalidate the signature.

Comment: thanks for the reply- in some solution i saw adding custom field [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49426086/how-to-add-more-data-in-access-token-jwt)  can i try similar to that

Comment: You can't change JWT token after it is was issued, JWT is immutable, signed data structure.

So, as I see you have two options...

First is to find out how to setup JWT generating/issuing with custom attributes/claims  in Keycloak, there are many built-in so called "mappers" or you can create you custom plugin for Keycloak. I recommend this article: https://www.baeldung.com/keycloak-custom-user-attributes

Second option is to find out how to enrich SecurityContext or RequestContext or HttpServletRequest with some details in your Spring Boot app, based on incoming JWT.

Answer (score 3):

To add claims, you have to do it from **authorization-server** (Keycloak in your case), not **resource-server** (REST API) nor **client**. This is obvious for JWTs (which are sealed with content signed by authorization-server), but should be respected for introspection too.

## Keycloak "mapper"

For Keycloak, private claims are added using "mappers". I have a complete sample in [this project](https://github.com/ch4mpy/user-proxies/tree/main/api/proxies-keycloak-mapper).

All you have to do is:

- pull Keycloak dependencies and add maven shade plugin to your build

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <!-- provided keycloak dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi-private</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-services</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

- provide `src/main/resources/META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml` with this content:

```xml
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-services" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

- provide `src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.keycloak.protocol.ProtocolMapper` with a content like (replace with your own mapper implementation):

```
com.c4_soft.user_proxies.api.keycloak.ProxiesMapper
```

- provide just above referenced mapper implementation using Keycloak base class and interfaces you need (`OIDCAccessTokenMapper` to add claims to access-tokens is probably a minimum in your case):

```java
public class ProxiesMapper extends AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper implements OIDCAccessTokenMapper, OIDCIDTokenMapper, UserInfoTokenMapper { }
```

- package and deploy to Keycloak `providers` directory (might need to run keycloak with `build` arg once as instructed in providers folder README)
- configure your new mapper from Keycloak administration UI (for the realm or individual clients)

## Parsing private claims in Spring

You can access all claims, including privates ones, from spring default Authentication implementations: `JwtAuthenticationToken::getTokenAttributes` (for JWT decoder) and `BearerTokenAuthentication::getTokenAttributes` (for introspection). Both return a `Map<String, Object>` you can use in security expressions.

You can also provide your own `Authentication` in place of Spring default ones and parse private claims there (return something more usefull than `Object` for the claims you use). Switching Authentication implementation is done the same way as switching authorities mapping:

```java
http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(...)
```

or

```java
http.oauth2ResourceServer().opaqueToken().authenticationConverter(...)
```

I have a set of 3 tutorials which incrementally explain how to easily parse (and use in security expression) such private claims: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials

Those tutorials are for servlets. If you are writing reactive applications, follow the tutorials and then refer to one of the [samples](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples) matching your exact configuration